# Update LiveTile with local data

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, live-tile

In my application I get rss feed from a website and than compare it with previously saved feed in isolated storage and show the updated feed. I want to update live tile with the updated feed items count, even when the app is not running. Kindly gave me guidelines for this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a background agent scheduler task. Depending on how resource intensive your call is, you can opt to use a Periodic tasks.

[see periodic tasks here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.scheduler.periodictask%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

[See an example of how to implement it here](http://mstruys.com/2011/11/18/every-windows-phone-application-deserves-a-live-tile-part-3/)

you have to note that the earliest a periodic task would run in wp7 is every 30 minutes. it is also subject to available resources on the device, hence it might not always run when you want it too.

Comment: Thanks. This example helped be to some extend. But i found answer on below link